# Mercury payment system

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment

I am trying to use a mercury payment system sending a API request and in return I am getting a payment id.
According to their documentation, after getting the payment id we have to send it as a post to their payment process host https://hc.mercurydev.net/CheckoutPOS.aspx
I am getting redirected to the page the amount is not showing properly.
Any suggestions?

Following is the request API

```
function get_ms_payment_id($ms_merchant_id,$ms_password,$order_header_id,$amount,$tax,$success_url,$failure_url)
{
    $soap_request = '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">';
    $soap_request .= '<SOAP-ENV:Body>';
    $soap_request .= '<InitializePayment xmlns="http://www.mercurypay.com/">';
    $soap_request .= '<request> ';
    $soap_request .= '<MerchantID>'.$ms_merchant_id.'</MerchantID> ';
    $soap_request .= '<Password>'.$ms_password.'</Password> ';
    $soap_request .= '<Invoice>'.$order_header_id.'</Invoice> ';
    $soap_request .= '<TotalAmount>50.23</TotalAmount>';
    $soap_request .= '<TaxAmount>'.$tax.'</TaxAmount>';
    $soap_request .= '<TranType>Sale</TranType> ';
    $soap_request .= '<Frequency>OneTime</Frequency>';
    $soap_request .= '<Memo>Your Memo</Memo> ';
    $soap_request .= '<PartialAuth>Off</PartialAuth> ';
    $soap_request .= '<ProcessCompleteUrl>'.$success_url.'</ProcessCompleteUrl> ';
    $soap_request .= '<ReturnUrl>'.$failure_url.'</ReturnUrl> ';
    $soap_request .= '<DisplayStyle>Custom</DisplayStyle>';
    $soap_request .= '<BackgroundColor>Gray</BackgroundColor>';
    $soap_request .= '<FontColor>Black</FontColor>';
    $soap_request .= '<FontFamily>FontFamily1</FontFamily>';
    $soap_request .= '<FontSize>Medium</FontSize>';
    $soap_request .= '<PageTitle>Demo Ecommerce Merchant</PageTitle>';
    $soap_request .= '<SecurityLogo>on</SecurityLogo>';
    $soap_request .= '<OrderTotal>on</OrderTotal>';
    $soap_request .= '<SubmitButtonText>Submit</SubmitButtonText>';
    $soap_request .= '<CancelButtonText>Cancel</CancelButtonText>';
    $soap_request .= '</request> ';
    $soap_request .= '</InitializePayment>';
    $soap_request .= '</SOAP-ENV:Body>';
    $soap_request .= '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

    $header = array("POST /ws/ws.asmx HTTP/1.1", 
        "Host: w1.mercurypay.com", 
        "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        "SOAPAction: \"http://www.mercurypay.com/InitializePayment\"");

    $url = "https://hc.mercurydev.net/hcws/hcservice.asmx";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soap_request);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    include_once('xml.php');
    $x_data = XML_unserialize($result);

    $x_data = $x_data["soap:Envelope"];
    $x_data = $x_data["soap:Body"];
    $x_data = $x_data["InitializePaymentResponse"];
    $result = $x_data["InitializePaymentResult"];

    return($result);
}
```

in response I am getting a valid paymentId, After using the paymentId I posting it to payment gateway
but the proper amount is not populating on payment gateway.

Following is the screenshot of the payment gateway

http://screencast.com/t/FbULkAy01X0L

Thank you

Comment: Show us some code, requests, something !

Comment: Thank you for your inquiry. You have laid out the issue well and provided good examples. With just a little more data we should be able to get this resolved. Can you send your HTML Form Post to DevelopSupportNotify@MercuryPay.com? With some additional communication I believe we can more easily determine what the issue is and find a resolution. Thank you, Developer Support
Mercury Payment Systems

Comment: where did you get the example code ?

Answer (score 2):

For an up to date integration of MercuryPay please check Aktive-Merchant implementation [of MercuryPay](https://github.com/akDeveloper/Aktive-Merchant/blob/master/lib/AktiveMerchant/Billing/Gateways/Mercury.php)

A short example is the following:

```
<?php
use AktiveMerchant\Billing\Base; //Use Base class
use AktiveMerchant\Billing\Mercury; //Use Mercury gateway
use AktiveMerchant\Billing\CreditCard;

Base::mode('test') // Remove this on production mode

$gateway = new Mercury(array('login'=>'<login>', 'password'=>'<password>'));

$credit_card = new CreditCard( 
    array(
        "first_name" => "John",
        "last_name" => "Doe",
        "number" => "41111111111111",
        "month" => "12",
        "year" => "2012",
        "verification_value" => "123"
    )
);

$credit_card->isValid(); // Returns true or false

# Extra options for transaction
$options = array(
    'order_id' => 'REF' . $gateway->generateUniqueId(),
    'description' => 'Test Transaction',
    'address' => array(
        'address1' => '1234 Street',
        'zip' => '98004',
        'state' => 'WA'
    )
);

$amount = 100; #100 cents 1.00 dollars

# Authorize transaction
$response = $gateway->authorize($amount, $credit_card, $options);
if ( $response->success() ) {
    echo 'Success Authorize';
} else {
    echo $response->message();
}
```

You can get the PaymentId from transaction as

`$response->authorization();`

Comment: Hi, i see the Gateway here https://github.com/akDeveloper/Aktive-Merchant
But i can find the way to install it with the composer. Need some help

Comment: You can run `composer require aktive_merchant/aktive_merchant` and then follow the instauction at https://github.com/akDeveloper/Aktive-Merchant/wiki/Usage.